# Collision Detection?

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering what route should I take to enable collision detection in my android app game. I have seen that it's easy to detect collision between shapes but I have already created the game using images drawn to the canvas. 
I've started but my code does not work

```
class EnemyShipProjectile extends GameObject {
        public EnemyShipProjectile(float x, float y, float dx, float dy, Drawable image) {
            super(x, y, dx, dy, image);
        }

        void move(Canvas canvas, EnemyShip enemyShip) {
            y += (2 * dy);
            if (y >= canvas.getHeight()) {
                y = 190;
                x = enemyShip.getXCoOrd()+10;
            }

            image.setBounds((int) x, (int) y, (int) (x + 30f), (int) (y + 40f));
            image.draw(canvas);
        }

        Boolean collision(float x, float y){
            Boolean collision = false;

            if(getXCoOrd()<= (x+80f) && getXCoOrd()>= (x-80f) && getYCoOrd() <= (y+80f) && getYCoOrd() >= (y-80f)){
                collision = true;
            }
            return collision;
        }
    }
```

When I call this method, true is always returned.

```
if (spaceshipProjectileSprite.collision(playerSprite.getXCoOrd(), playerSprite.getYCoOrd()) == true) {
            //Update player life total
            updateLifeTotal();
        }
```

Comment: And have you checked the coordinates of the two objects?

Comment: What is `GameObject`? Is this your own class or is it from a 3rd-party library?

Comment: As for the behavior of your `collision()` function, I suggest that you use a debugger to determine why it always returns true. Where do the `x` and `y` parameters in `collision()` come from?

Comment: One unrelated suggestion: use `bool` rather than `Boolean`. For details, I suggest you learn about the difference between primitive types and wrapper classes.

Comment: I think we need more information. If your collision is returning true then I'd assume that either the projectile is being registered as still being in the player or the player is for some reason on the projectile.

It would be interesting to see the player class. 

If you think the projectile or the player is not moving correctly then I'd look at what might cause that e.g. what happens if you try to move the projectile or the player? Use a debugger or add print statements to see the x & y values before the colision check.